# Static IP route will not clear

Tags: routing, brocade

I have a Brocade FESX648-PREM I set a static route with the following command:

```
ip route 123.123.123.123 255.255.255.255 124.124.124.124
```

Where 123.123.123.123 is my real IP address and 124.124.124.124 is an intentionally incorrect next hop IP.

Since, 124.124.124.124 is an invalid next hop IP, 123.123.123.123 stops pinging immediately.

However, when I clear the route with `no ip route 123.123.123.123 255.255.255.255 124.124.124.124` the 123.123.123.123 still does not ping.

If I follow up with  `clear ip route 123.123.123.123 255.255.255.255` the IP again will continue to not ping.

If I run a `show ip route 123.123.123.123`, I can see that it is correctly routing to the default gateway.

However, if I `write memory` and `reload` the switch, then the IP will ping again.

It was suggested to me that I should verify that my `ip-route` and `ip-cache` entries are not exceeding their `system-max` values, but that checked out OK as well:

> Total number of IP routes: 64382, avail: 15618 (out of max 80000)
>
> Total number of cache entries: 303

Any ideas why this route is getting "stuck"?

**EDIT:** I found a workaround. 1. Remove the invalid static route, 2. manually set the correct static route, 3. clear the route set in the previous step. Strange, seems like this should not be necessary. If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions on resolving the core issue, I'd still be very happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there another existing routing protocol, default route, or static-route that would begin to take precedence once the less explicit route entry is removed?

Does placing a static-route that is correct (valid next-hop) allow pings to flow again?

Comment: The only other static routes in the config pertain to inapplicable prefixes. I do accept the default route via BGP (as well as a variety of other routes from an IXP), but if those were creating an issue I'd expect to see it reflected in `show ip route`. Upvoted for the placing the correct static route suggestion -- that is part of the workaround I discovered a short while ago.

Comment: If you have a valid alternative route, then deleting the faulty route should clear the path. You definitely aren't going crazy. As a matter of fact, you may well have found some intricacy of the unit that needs to be brought up with the manufacturer, or may even be addressed in another code revision. I've encountered such strange behavior on devices much older than the Brocade series of L3-capable switches, so it isn't a stretch to believe that you uncovered a defect.